# How to get the fully qualified path name in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, path, fully-qualified-naming

Is there a function that returns the fully qualified path name for any inputted file?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
LPCSTR path = "foo.bar"
LPCSTR fullPath = FullyQualifiedPath(path);
//fullPath now equals C:\path\to\foo.bar
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a platform-dependent question. It sounds like you're using Win32?

Comment: As an aid to future searches: The **fully qualified path name** is often referred to as the **absolute path**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Win32, call the [`GetFullPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Note that on NTFS, with hard links especially, this returns one of the full path names of the file (if it only has one, then it doesn't matter).  Just a head's up.

Answer (score 3):

Use boost::filesystem
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path p = boost::filesystem::complete("foo.bar");
    std::cout << p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't use any external libraries.